# How can I exclude certain packages from the exports with bndwrap

Tags: ant, osgi, bnd

The existing jar that I am trying to wrap with the ant *bndwrap* task has the classes from another jar included within it.  By this I mean the unrolled jar, not an embedded jar.

How can I omit these packages from the export packages declaration of the bundle?

Basically the jar has the packages

```
org.stuff
```

and

```
org.otherstuff
```

I want to only export the org.stuff package, but bndwrap will include both.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Export-Package in the bnd file, you can define exclusion as well with a "!".

Example from http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd:

```
Export-Package: !com.acme.impl, com.acme.*;version=1.2
```

Also, if you use wrapping, -exportcontents can be interesting for you: http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Wrapping:

"The binaries and sources are not in the final jar but bnd does not yet know what needs to be exported. This can be indicated with the -exportcontents instruction. It has the same syntax as Export-Package but does not copy from the classpath, it only applies the instruction to the content of the final JAR."

Comment: Will that exclusion export alone remove the unwanted exports, but still include the auto generated exports? I don't want to specifically include exports as I don't want to have to keep the version in bnd file in sync with the ant build.  I would rather it is derived from the existing content of the jar, which includes a bundle version.

Comment: How does the existing content of the jar include the bundle version? In the MANIFEST as OSGi headers or in another way?

Comment: Note that it is important that the exclusions appear BEFORE any wildcard inclusions.